# AssetManager is not working from NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-3.0

I am working with OpenGL ES 3.0 and using Eclipse NDK for rendering volume data with Google Nexus.
I am using AssetManager for loading the volume data which is a raw file of 16 MB to the real device but it's not working. I stored the resource in the Asset folder included headers too but still i am receiving the same  error in logcat __load_uniform_float:802>:GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
I tried to Google some related examples but couldn't find any.

Here is my code:

```
int LoadVolume()
{
    GLubyte *pdata;
    const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = XDIM*YDIM*ZDIM;
    GLubyte buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    AAssetManager*mgr;
    AAsset* asset=AAssetManager_open(mgr,"Engine256.raw",AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
    if(!asset)
    {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TAG", "_ASSET_NOT_FOUND_");
     return 0;
    }
    pdata=(GLubyte*)AAsset_read(asset,buffer,BUFFER_SIZE);

    AAsset_close(asset);

   glGenTextures ( 1,&textureId );
   glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_3D,textureId );
   glTexImage3D ( GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RED,XDIM, YDIM, ZDIM, 0,
                  GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pdata);

   glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
   glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
   glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
   glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

   glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0 );
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Iam unable to add the code,how to do it?

Comment: copy your code and paste it and select the complete code and format it by using Control+k

Comment: Please specify what is not working. Don't let us guess please. Which line causes the error? How much is buffer size actually?

Comment: You are loading the file in memory (not to the device) and do nothing with the content in buffer. Now where is the code error line?

Comment: i just started ndk a few days back so i have no idea.there is no error shown in line but failed to load data and i dont know the reason.

Comment: can you tell me how to load the file in device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at these two lines:

```
AAssetManager*mgr;
AAsset* asset=AAssetManager_open(mgr,"Engine256.raw",AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
```

You're declaring `mgr` as a pointer variable, but you don't assign a value to it. Then you use it on the next line, while it's uninitialized.

You need to pass an `AssetManager` object from your Java code into the native code through your JNI interface, and then obtain the `AAssetManager` by using this call, where `assetManager` is the Java object passed in, which comes into the native code as a `jobject` type parameter.

```
AAssetManager *mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
```

This question/answer show in some more detail how to pass the Java object to the native code:
[Can't access AAssetManager in native code passed from Java in WallpaperService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941802/cant-access-aassetmanager-in-native-code-passed-from-java-in-wallpaperservice).