# Opening a file with AAssetManager crashes

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

**Sometimes** AAssetManager crashes on me. The exact trace is below.

```
#00 pc 00000000000cdd91  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+1) (BuildId: fa337969c798946280caa45e2d71a2e7)
#01 pc 0000000000050115  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::mutex::lock()+5) (BuildId: 3324cfa90a3aa967ca9e5c4269b1b7f2)
#02 pc 0000000000018875  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (AAssetManager_open+53) (BuildId: 094d5e744838e61070f3b00f0a8d3c31)
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941802/cant-access-aassetmanager-in-native-code-passed-from-java-in-wallpaperservice) the error is caused by an invalid Java object reference.
My code for loading the asset manager from Java is below:

```java
public class MainActivity extends SDLActivity
{

    private AssetManager mgr;

    native void initAManager(AssetManager mgr);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mgr = this.getAssets();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initAManager(mgr);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

```c
static jobject omgr = NULL;
static AAssetManager* gmgr = NULL;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_MainActivity_initAManager(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject mgr) {
    omgr = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, mgr);
    gmgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, omgr);
}

/* ... */

int open_file(struct ctx mctx, char* name) {
    if((*mctx->env)->IsSameObject(mctx->env, omgr, NULL)) {
        log_print("Asset manager object is invalid"); // I don't see this line ever in logs!
    }
    
    AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(gmgr, name, AASSET_MODE_RANDOM); // This line crashes
    /* ... */
}
```

I tried to load the asset manager later in my application, by getting methods from the JNI and then executing them, but it seemed the asset manager would get garbage collected (the reference object to was equal to NULL). Also I originally was trying this on an older toolchain, but updated doesn't change anything.

Comment: I believe I solved this, but that could just be side-effects of delayed execution or something. I set my assets not to be compressed, (And added some code that takes some time to execute, maybe the problem was that my program tried to access assets too quickly but they weren't uncompressed yet.) and opening them worked. So if anyone has the **real** solution, please post it here.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Read the assets from C Code?

Comment: @Cristi yes, but I think the asset manager got garbage collected before I could use it sometimes because at one point in testing, the asset manager reference was successfully compared to NULL (through jni functions), but later the same did not apply.